# how to remove unwanted vertical white space in visual studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have problem with unwanted vertical space in my asp.net design page.. I don't know that how to remove. please help me.how to remove unwanted vertical white space in visual studio 2013? I used this regular expression "^$\n" to remove unwanted spaces. but its not working.

Comment: You mean source page?

Comment: Yes. In my aspx page.

Comment: You can do using Replace this regex ^(?([^\r\n])\s)*\r?$\r?\n with nothing and you will be able to delete white space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select All using `Ctrl+A`, then press `Ctrl+K+D`, to auto-format your ASPX Source file, you can also do this by Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document.

Comment: I have already tired this method. but its not working

Comment: @Kani - I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, proper formatting that's it right? Why you are bothering so much abt that, is will not hamper your response.

Comment: I have at least 20 empty lines between each and every line.more difficult to work with that screen. That's why i am asking.

Answer (score 0):

I cant understand your post correctly, but if you reffer to vertical space in a Page wich is not controlled in your code, Try setting the next CSS in HTML:

```
html
{
  margin: 0;
}
```

or test with

```
body
{
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Lot of unwanted vertical spaces appear when I opened my design page. I am too tired to delete those lines.

Comment: Can you insert a print screen to see the problem please.

Comment: I cant insert image for reputation problem.